# BCP QUERYOUT how to change length to all decimal fields

Tags: decimal, ssms, bcp, application-settings, maxlength

I export `SQL` tables to txt files (by the code below in `ssms`)
all the columns are exported well except decimal columns,
which export 41 chars (I want 19 chars),
even the size column is 14(4)
**how can I change the settings in order the column will export in the size I want?**

notes:
bcp export `0.0` decimal value as `.0000` as I need
my tables is very big can't use substring- a lot of columns and a lot of rows

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 

RECONFIGURE

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 

RECONFIGURE
-------------
DECLARE @stmtQuery VARCHAR(8000),@stmt VARCHAR(8000);
       
----שליפת הנתונים מהטבלה
set @stmtQuery ='SELECT  * FROM myDB.dbo.HugeTable' --a lot of decimal columns, a lot of rows

--copy data to txt file
SET @stmt = 'BCP "' + @stmtQuery +
'" QUERYOUT "path\to\file\TableData.txt"  -t -C RAW   -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' +  DB_NAME()+' -e path\to\file\log.txt -c  -r"0x0A" -T';
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast your decimal columns to varchar before export with bcp

```
set @stmtQuery ='SELECT convert(varchar,MyDecimalColumn) as ColumnName FROM myDB.dbo.HugeTable'
```

alternatively you can use the FORMAT() function if you're using MSSQL 2012+

```
set @stmtQuery ='SELECT FORMAT(MyDecimalColumn,''00000.0000000000'') as ColumnName FROM myDB.dbo.HugeTable'
```

i'll hope it helps